# Can I disable the "highlight on click" behavior of ImageMapster?

Tags: jquery, imagemapster

I want to use ImageMapster as a "nonintelligent storage" for highlights. I'm using it with AngularJS, and I need to track the highlight state etc inside the Angular scope. But I'm running into problems when I click on a highlight area, because Mapster sets it's own state and this is clashing with my Angular scope.

I want all the other features, I just want the highlight on click event action to be disabled inside mapster. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the option `staticState: false` e.g.

```
$('img').mapster({
    staticState: false
});
```

This says every area is always off. (You could also use `staticState: true` to make every area always appear selected).

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/jamietre/T9nPX/

Comment: THANK YOU! I've been battling this problem for *days* now, and I *knew* there was something in the docs, something in the options... but I failed to find this :)